# Vetor sem números repetidos em C

Tags: c

Como faço para carregar um vetor, que o usuário informe todos os valores, que não possa ter números repetidos?

Por exemplo, um vetor de 20 posições que pede para o usuário informar cada valor, e, ao informar um valor igual a qualquer um anterior, uma mensagem apareceria e seria necessário informar outro valor.

Meu código até o momento:

```
main()
{
    printf("Insira os dados do vetor A\n");

    for(i = 0; 20 > i; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",va[i]);
        auxva = va[i];

        for(j = 0; 20 > j; j++)
        { 
            if (va[j] == auxva)
            {
                printf("Sem valores repetidos\n");
                scanf("%d",&auxva);
            }

            if(va[j] != auxva) 
                continue;
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: A cada valor informado, você precisará percorrer todo o vetor atual verificando se o valor coincide com pelo menos um valor presente no vetor. Se sim, solicitar novamente o número, se não, inserí-ro. Você tem alguma tentativa que fez e deu errado?

Comment: main(){
  printf("Insira os dados do vetor A\n");
  for(i=0;20>i;i++){
       scanf("%d",va[i]);
       auxva = va[i];
       for(j=0;20>j;j++){
            if (va[j]==auxva){
                 printf("Sem valores repetidos\n");
                 scanf("%d",&auxva);
                }
            if(va[j]!=auxva)
                continue;
           }
      }
  }
Tinha feito algo assim, ainda tô meio perdido, mas acho q a ideia ja tá mais ou menos certa, obrigado!

Comment: Beto, adicionei seu código direto na pergunta. Como é novo aqui, recomendo que você faça o [tour] para entender o básico de como o site funciona. Lá encontrará tudo o que precisa para utilizar bem o site, tal como dicas de como perguntar, como formatar perguntas e respostas, etc.

Comment: Três comentários: 1. Você não declarou nenhuma variável no seu exemplo, assim ele não tem como compilar. 2. aquele `if (va[j] != auxva) continue;` é redundante: se você tirá-lo completamente não altera o comportamento do código. 3. Foi o seu professor que she ensinou a escrever `20 > i` e `20 > j` nos laços `for`?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int exists(int *numbers, int size, int n) {
    for (register int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] == n)
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

void printArray(int *numbers, int size) {
    for (register int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", numbers[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int size = 20;
    int *numbers = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    int count = 0;
    int n;

    while (count < size) {
        printf("Digite um número!\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);

        if (exists(numbers, size, n) == 0) {
            printf("Inserindo número no array\n");
            numbers[count] = n;
            count++;
        } else {
            printf("Número já existe\n");
        }
    }

    printf("O array é:\n");
    printArray(numbers, size);
}
```

Comment: Então amigo, não cheguei na parte de arrays ainda, minha matéria está no começo de vetores em C. Há alguma solução usando só conceitos básicos como estruturas de repetição?

Comment: Nesse exemplo eu estou utilizando apenas um vetor unidimensional e estruturas de repetição. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
//Codigo Simples
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int i,j,n,vetor[20];

    int bandeira = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        scanf("%d", &n);
        //verifica se o numero digitato é igual a algum anterior
        for(j = 0; j <= i-1 ; j++){
            if(n == vetor[j]){
                bandeira = 1;
                //Caso encontre, a bandeira recebe 1 e o
                //"for" verificador é quebrado para economizar
                //processamento.
                break;
            }
        }
        //Se a bandeira é igual a 1, isso
        //significa que existe um numero igual
        if(bandeira == 1){
            printf("%d repetido \n", n);
            bandeira = 0;
            //A variavel "i" recebe menos 1, para garantir que o "i"
            // só vai referenciar a próxima posição do vetor quando o
            //usuário NÃO digitar um número repetido.
            //A bandeira é zerada para poder ser reutilizada.
            i -= 1;
        }else{
            //Caso não houver numero repetido, o numero é colocado
            //no vetor.
            vetor[i] = n;
        }
    }

    //Mostrar o vetor.

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%d ", vetor[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <cstdio>

int vetorA[4];
int i, k;

int main()
{
    printf("\nDigite 4 elementos para o Conjunto A:\n");
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){//Carregando o vetor
        printf("Digite o valor %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &vetorA[i]);

        for(k=0;k<=i-1;k++){//Verificando se o valor já digitado antes
            if(vetorA[i]==vetorA[k]){
                printf("Valor %d ja exite no Conjunto\n", vetorA[i]);
                i-=1;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nConjunto A = { ");//Imprimindo o conjunto

    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        printf("%d, ", vetorA[i]);
    }
        printf("}\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TAM_VETOR 5

int main()
{
    int vetor[TAM_VETOR] = {0};//zera tudo que tive la dentro
    int qtdInseridos = 0;//Quantos numeros ja foram inseridos
    int n;//valor que o cara coloca

    register int a;//contadores de loop


    for( ; qtdInseridos < TAM_VETOR; )
    {
        scanf("%d", &n);

        for(a = 0; a < qtdInseridos; a++)
            if( vetor[a] == n )
                break;

        if( a == qtdInseridos ) //passou por todo o for sem encontra nenhum numero igual a N, logo "a" é igual "qtdInseridos"
            vetor[qtdInseridos++] = n;
        else
            printf("Numero repetido.\n");

    }

    //Printa o vetor
    for(a = 0; a < TAM_VETOR; a++)
        printf("%d ", vetor[a]);
    printf("\n");

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Se você vai fazer `for (; qtdInseridos < TAM_VETOR; )`, é melhor fazer `while (qtdInseridos < TAM_VETOR)`, em vez disso.

Comment: @Wtrmute aew ja é mais uma questão de gosto